# How can i fix the font size in XFCE after installing a proprietary graphic driver

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, fonts, display-settings, appearance

After installing the Nvidia driver of my graphic card the font size becomes very tiny, how can i restore his size (I am Using Linux Mint 18.1 XFCE).

Answer (score 5):

It's a bug, to restore the font size go in the Appearence settings, in the Fonts tab and uncheck then re-check Custom DPI and this will fix your problem.

[image]

Comment: Correct answer, fixed my issue caused by installing nvidia proprietary graphic driver ( OS: Pardus 21, Desktop: XFCE 4.16 ).