# XFCE font resets size every reboot

Tags: nvidia, xfce, endeavouros

I'm running EndeavourOS with XFCE4. I ran the installer for NVIDIA GPUs which installs drivers afaik. I have the same issue described in this question: [How can i fix the font size in XFCE after installing a proprietary graphic driver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362282/how-can-i-fix-the-font-size-in-xfce-after-installing-a-proprietary-graphic-drive)

The solution works for me (changing AA or DPI setting and then changing it back). However I have to do this every time I reboot because the error reappears. How can I apply this fix automatically on boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't use NVIDIA, as you mentioned that changing the DPI works for you.

This command will set the DPI to 100:

```
xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Xft/DPI -t int -s 100
```

---

To understand how to get the properties and values, use the xfconf-query command to monitor changes.

First, find out the channel name. In this case, use the xsettings channel.

List the channel names with xfconf-query -m.

```
$ xfconf-query -m
Channels:
  xfce4-settings-editor
  xfce4-appfinder
  thunar
  xfce4-power-manager
  xsettings
  xfce4-settings-manager
  displays
  keyboards
  xfce4-session
  xfce4-desktop
  xfwm4
  xfce4-notifyd
  xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts
  keyboard-layout
  pointers
  xfce4-panel
```

Monitor the settings with:

```
xfconf-query -m -c xsettings
```

Now go to your settings from UI, and change the DPI. Come back to the terminal, and you see the command like this:

```
xfconf-query -m -c xsettings
Start monitoring channel "xsettings":

set: /Xfce/LastCustomDPI
set: /Xft/DPI
set: /Xfce/LastCustomDPI
set: /Xft/DPI
```

So we found out the property name, and we can use the command to change the DPI to 100 for example:

```
xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Xft/DPI -t int -s 100
```

Here:

- `-c`: Channel name. xsettings in our case.
- `-p`: Property name. /Xft/DPI in our case.
- `-t`: Type. `int` (integer) in our case
- `-s` Set. Set to 100 in our case.

---

Use that command in Settings -> `Session and Startup` -> `Application Autostart` -> `+ Add` -> Add name and the command. Choose proper trigger, in this case most likely `on login`.

If the DPI setting doesn't seem to take effect, you can try a workaround by creating a BASH script that first sets the DPI to an arbitrary value (like 99), waits for a short period, and then sets it to the desired value (like 100).

Here's how you can do it:

```bash
xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Xft/DPI -t int -s 99

sleep 0.5

xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Xft/DPI -t int -s 100
```

Run the bash script straight from autostart.